# How to group the JSON object by a key using JSONata

Tags: json, jsonata

I want to use **JSONata** to do the grouping of json objects in an array based on a key within the JSON object.

For example, I want to group the cars based on their names for the JSON example given below.

```
[
  {
    "car" : "audi",
    "color" : "blue",
    "reg" : 133434
  },
   {
    "car" : "benz",
    "color" : "red",
    "reg" : 134444
  },
   {
    "car" : "audi",
    "color" : "red",
    "reg" : 134884
  }
]
```

*Expected output*

```
{
  "audi" : [
    {
    "car" : "audi",
    "color" : "blue",
    "reg" : 133434
    },
    {
    "car" : "audi",
    "color" : "red",
    "reg" : 134884
    }
  ],
  "benz" : [
    {
    "car" : "benz",
    "color" : "red",
    "reg" : 134444
    }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [javascript | Object grouping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21776389/javascript-object-grouping)

Comment: I don't think that this question is a duplicate as it asks explicitly for a JSONata query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$${car: [$.{"car": car, "color": color, "reg": reg}]}
```

The documentation almost gives the solution:

https://docs.jsonata.org/sorting-grouping

To make sure that the values (even if there is only a single one) for each group is stored in an array, an explicit list construction with `[...]` is needed.

Comment: Thanks a lot CC. The query expression shared gave more insight than the samples in the document.

Answer (score 0):

```
const list =[
  {
    "car" : "audi",
    "color" : "blue",
    "reg" : 133434
  },
   {
    "car" : "benz",
    "color" : "red",
    "reg" : 134444
  },
   {
    "car" : "audi",
    "color" : "red",
    "reg" : 134884
  }
]

const groups = list.reduce((groups, item) => {
  const group = (groups[item.car] || []);
  group.push(item);
  groups[item.car] = group;
  return groups;
}, {});

console.log(groups);
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.