# Grouping two array dates

Tags: javascript, arrays, date

I want to combine data with the same date in the array.
I'm not good enough, so I can't think of a code to make it come out like a result
I'd appreciate it if you could help me

```js
const list1 = [{
  date: "2022-10-01",
  images: [{image: "01"}, {image: "02"}, {image: "03"}]
        }]
const list2 = [{
    date: "2022-10-01",
    images: [{ image: "04"}]
     },
     {date: "2022-10-02",
      images: [{image: "05"}, {image: "06"}, { image: "07"}]
     }
   ]


result = [{
    date: "2022-10-01",
    images: [{image: "01"}, {image: "02"}, {image: "03"}, {image: "04"}]
  },
  {
    date: "2022-10-02",
    images: [{image: "05"}, {image: "06"}, {image: "07"}]
  }
]
```

Comment: So as i understood you want to concat objects with same date? I can not see where you have removed duplicates

Comment: Does this answer your question? [javascript | Object grouping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21776389/javascript-object-grouping)

Answer (score 0):

You could start concatenating `list1` and `list2`.

Then you could iterate the whole array, and for each item check whether you already stored in result an object with the same date value.

If that's the case, you `concat` the images array for that item, otherwise you `push` the item in result.

```js
const list1 = [{
  date: "2022-10-01",
  images: [{
    image: "01"
  }, {
    image: "02"
  }, {
    image: "03"
  }]
}]
const list2 = [{
    date: "2022-10-01",
    images: [{
      image: "04"
    }]
  },
  {
    date: "2022-10-02",
    images: [{
      image: "05"
    }, {
      image: "06"
    }, {
      image: "07"
    }]
  }
]


const expectedResult = [{
    date: "2022-10-01",
    images: [{
      image: "01"
    }, {
      image: "02"
    }, {
      image: "03"
    }, {
      image: "04"
    }]
  },
  {
    date: "2022-10-02",
    images: [{
      image: "05"
    }, {
      image: "06"
    }, {
      image: "07"
    }]
  }
]


const both = list1.concat(list2)
const result = []

for (const obj of both) {
  const index = result.findIndex(r => r.date === obj.date)

  if (index >= 0) {
    result[index].images = result[index].images.concat(obj.images)
  } else {
    result.push(obj)
  }
}

console.log(result)

console.log(JSON.stringify(result) === JSON.stringify(expectedResult))
```