# need to calculate sum of amt of an array of objects but when vid is not same it should push that into new array as an object

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
const array = [ 
    {address:'12312',vid:'1',amt:'0.1'},
    {address:'12312',vid:'1',amt:'0.1'},
    {address:'12312',vid:'2',amt:'0.1'},
];
```

the result I want is `[{address:'12312',vid:'1',amt:'0.2'},{address:'12312',vid:'',amt:'0.1'}]`

```js
var totalAmt = 0;
var count = 0;
var vid = []
var result = [];
array.forEach(element => {
    if(!vid.includes(element.vid)){
        totalAmt = totalAmt + Number(element.amt); 
        vid.push({vid:element.vid,total:totalAmt});     
    }else {
        console.log("lakalaka");
        // totalAmt = totalAmt + Number(element.amt);
    }
});
console.log(totalAmt,vid);
```

Need to calculate sum of  amt of an array of objects  but when vid is not same it should push that into new array as an object
thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you _really_ want `vid:''` in your result for what was `2` in your input data?

Comment: `vid.includes(element.vid)` - that should never be true. Your items in vids are these objects, but you are trying to compare them with a scalar value here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to group the items with `vid` and then sum `amt` of each group items.

```js
const array = [{
    address: '12312',
    vid: '1',
    amt: '0.1'
  },
  {
    address: '12312',
    vid: '1',
    amt: '0.1'
  },
  {
    address: '12312',
    vid: '2',
    amt: '0.1'
  },
];

const groups = array.reduce((groups, item) => ({
  ...groups,
  [item.vid]: [...(groups[item.vid] || []), item]
}), {});


const result = Object.values(groups).map(group => group.reduce((acc, item, index) => {
  return {
    ...acc,
    amt: +acc.amt + +item.amt
  }
}))

console.log(result)
```

[Source of group function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54203304/11887902)